# How to determine the length of JSON containing object inside object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to get the length from the following:

```
{
    "11": {
        "id": "456",
        "uuid": "b596362a-b5bb-4n94-8fd5-1e9fh6fd877b",
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test"
    },
    "22": {
        "id": "739",
        "uuid": "c4ccbddf-5177-482f-b5e8-cdd4f699e6b7",
        "name": "Test2",
        "description": "Test2"
    },
    "33": {
        "id": "737",
        "uuid": "m4ccbddv-5177-482f-b5e8-cdd4f699e6b7",
        "name": "Test3",
        "description": "Test3"
    }
}
```

The length should be 3. I tried to use `JSON.stringify(data).length` but this gives the length of the whole string.

Comment: Please use the search :P

Comment: Or are you literally asking how to get the number of properties from an object *encoded as JSON*, without decoding it into a native JS value? It appears you are mistakenly calling a JS object "JSON" (which is a common mistake unfortunately), but I could be wrong. In other words, is `data` an *object* or a *string containing JSON*?

Comment: Its a JSON string coming by applying `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: So, if `data` is a "JSON string", why are you calling `JSON.stringify` on it *again*? Since you accepted once of the answers it seems I am right in assuming you are actually working with an object.

Comment: No, I am not calling again. I am just printing it in console using `JSON.stringify` to get data. The original one was `JSON.stringify($rootScope.data)` which gave the JSON string as I shown you here. I just said that I used `JSON.stringify($rootScope.data).length` to get the length of that.

Comment: Then it seems you misunderstood my comment. I asked you what the value of `data` is, which is what you are passing to `JSON.stringify`: `JSON.stringify(data).length`. Anyways, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to above answer, apparently, modern browsers have an `Object.keys` function. In this case, you could do this:

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length;
```

You can use following function

```
function getJsonItemLength(item) {
  if (typeof item !== undefined && varNotNull(item) && item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            return item.length;
        } else if (typeof item === 'object' ) {
            return Object.keys(item).length;
        } else if (typeof item === 'string' ) {
            return item.length
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The other answers are also all suggesting `Object.keys`. How is yours different? Which "above answer" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you get the list of keys (in an array) so you could:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the length of an associative-array-like object, that's your answer: [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array)

Or to save you the click:

```
Object.keys(myObj).length;
```